# How can I align warped images to create a panoramic image?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to create a panorama and I am stuck on the part where I have two separate warped images in two `cv::Mat`'s and now I need to align them and create one single `cv::Mat`. I also need to average the pixel color value where the pixels in the images overlap to do elementary blending. Is there a built in function in opencv that can do this for me? I have been following the [Basic Stitching Pipeline](https://sites.google.com/site/ritpanoramaapp/project-stage-iii). I'm not sure how I can align and blend the images. I looked up a solution that does feature matching between the images and then we get the homography and just use the translation vector to align the images. Is this what I should be using?

Here are the warped images:

Image 1:

[image]

Image 1:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Generating a panaroma from a set of images is usually done using homographies. The reason for this is explained very well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21927434/5484662).

You can refer to the code given by Eduardo [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/60332/panorama-mosaic-from-aerial-images/). It is also based on feature matching though.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, you need to start with finding descriptors for features in the image (Brief descriptor might be a good idea) and then do feature matching. Once you have the correspondences, you will use those correspondences to estimate the homography. The homography will help you warp one of the image with respect to the other. Post this, you can simply blend them together (by simply add the two images, or taking the maximum value of the at each pixel between the two images)